# Apache Poi, Using Xssf Type

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi

I'm using maven, and need to use both xls and xlsx types of Excel file.

In pom.xml, poi's dependency is already determined by someone(before I join).

here's pom.xml dependencies.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.6</version>
<scope>test<scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.1-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

I read an article that poi and poi-ooxml's version should be same,

but I couldn't find poi-ooxml which matches with poi 3.1-FINAL.

If I change poi's version in pom.xml, then other old codes(use Hssf Format)

show errors. and I added libraries by Adding jar files from external as well,

it falied, too.

Is there any way to add poi-ooxml??

Comment: You doomed to port legacy code to support the current version of POI. It would be simpler than playing with different classloaders for different parts of your application.

Comment: OOXML support was only added in 3.5